# Grouping files based on info gathered from parsing through file name

Tags: parsing, awk, ksh

I am writing a process using KSH. I will have to go through numerous files in a single directory, and group the files together based on information gathered from parsing through the file name. The problem is that there are no "delimiters" in the file names (such as periods or underscores).

Here is a sample of one of the files:    0997dept4fec81ae.dcn

The 0997 is the store number. The files first need to be grouped by store. I can handle that part. The text after the store number is the file "type". I think I can weasel my way through and parse out the file type. The next 6 characters is really what I need to parse out. I should be able to "group" the files together based on these 6 characters.

So, what is the best way to do this? One caveat: Once I get these files grouped together, I then need to have them process oldest files first, per store.

Comment: Essentially, because the leading characters of the file name have no delimiters or set number of characters, I think I need to 'awk' backwards through the file name, if that's possible.

Comment: Is the department "4f" (that leaves 6 characters before the dot)? Is there some pattern to the name or is it fixed width "fields"? Show some more sample names that represent the range of variation. Is this on Linux or Unix (which Unix)?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can split things out with awk like:

```
ls *.dcn |awk 'BEGIN{FS=".";a[0]=0;a[1]=4;a[2]=9;a[3]=16}{for(i=0;i<3;i++){printf("%s\t",substr($1,a[i]+1,a[i+1]-a[i]));}printf("\n");}'
```

This is pretty inelegant, and assumes that the fields you want to separate have a constant width (you didn't give info otherwise).  You can look for other string manipulation functions here:

[Awk String Manipulation](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/ch09_02.htm)

After you separate with something like above you can probably pipe it to another script or command and sort.

Answer (score 0):

I might not be adding anything here, but I tend to find command line perl useful for something like this.

```
print "0997dept4fec81ae.dcn 
0997dept4fec81ae.dcz
0997dept5fec81ae.dcn 
0997dept5fec81ae.dcz" | perl -ne '
chomp ;

if (/\d+\w{4}(.{6})/) {
    my $group = $1 ;

    push @{$h{$group}}, $_ ;
}

END { 
    for (sort keys %h) {
        print "Group: $_\n" ;

        print "\t$_\n" for sort @{$h{$_}} ;
    } 
} '
```

shows the idea.

Like the last post - you can pipe that to something like

find command | perl inline bit | while read Group Filename
do

print "$Group, $Filename"

other things

done

This bod's webpage is good for a guide to cmd line perl: http://wwwx.cs.unc.edu/~jsterrel/articles/perl-cli.php

But I guess it depends how clear you find awk or perl.